# Redux - What is immutable state change for reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Two functions to change reducer state:

```
function1 (state, newValue) {
    const newValue1 = newValue + 1;
    const newValue2 = newValue * 7;
    return {...state, newValue2}
}

function2 (state, newValue) {
    let newValue1 = newValue + 1;
    newValue1 = newValue1 * 7;
    return {...state, newValue1}
}
```

Which one is correct? Does only state has to be immutable or any variable?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. As you've said, only the state has to be immutable. In your case, simply don't mutate the `state` variable in any way.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind an immutable state object is just that you don't change `state` directly. So doing this would be wrong:

```js
let state = {...}
function changeState(newValue) {
  state.newValue = newValue
}
```

I don't know the rest of your code to say it's right or wrong, but in the examples you provided, you are not mutating state - you're returning a new object that takes everything from the existing state as-is (destructuring state with `...state`) and adding or overriding `newValue` in the newly returned object.

As to whether or not it's wrong to change `newValue` (or other variables), again both of your instances are fine. It's perfectly find to use, change, and run logic in your reducers to ultimately come up with a new object (or whatever) for the updated state.

Comment: Why shouldnt one change state directly?

Comment: Immutability is required by redux. Check out this page for a discussion and reasoning: https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data#what-are-the-benefits-of-immutability